# Strange behaviour of spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA and I have a case where in my opinion JoinColumn behaves different and I want to know why.

UserEntites should join authorites.

Organziations should join OrganizationSettings.

I have two different approaches and both work.

**Case 1**

UserEntity :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private List<UserAuthority> authorities;
}
```

UserAuthoritiesEntity

```
@Entity(name = "authorities")
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class UserAuthority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long userId;

    private String authority;
}
```

Here in my opinion the JoinColumn name references to UserAuthority.userId - and it works as expected.

**Case 2**

See my two other classes:

OrganizationEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="organization")
public class OrganizationEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id",updatable = false)
    private OrganizationSettingsEntity settings;
}
```

OrganizationSettings:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "organization_settings")
public class OrganizationSettingsEntity {

    @Id
    private Long organizationId;
}
```

As you can see here -> Organization is Joining OrganizationSettings with the name id - which works. But in OrganizationSettings there is no id - just organizationId. This works - but makes me wonder.

Why does the second one also work? Shouldn't it be `@JoinColumn(name="organizationId")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is nothing to do with it. JPA is a standard API.

1-N case : you will create a FK column in the `authorities` table with name `userId` (linking back to the `users` table). You seem to also want to REUSE that same column for this `userId` field in the element ... this will cause you problems sooner or later since reusing columns without marking the `userId` field as `insertable=false, updatable=false` will mean that both may try to update it. Either get rid of the `userId` field in the element, or convert the field to be of type `UserEntity` (and have it as a bidirectional relation, using `mappedBy` on the 1-N owner field), or mark the `userId` field with those attributes mentioned earlier.

1-1 case : you will create a FK column in the `organization` table with name `id` (linking across to the `organization_settings` table). Sadly this is the same column as the PK of that table is going to use, so again you are reusing the column for 2 distinct purposes, and hell will result. Change the column of the relation FK to something distinct - the FK is in the `organization` table, not the other side.

Comment: Thanks @neil - but I find it kind of strange with the 1-1 case.
When i normally build my MySQL tables (without JPA) I have for example the id as PK in users and then in an extended table - say users_mentors - a user_id. 
This is in my opinion quite standard. 
Can you show a little code on what to do - then maybe I understand better :)

Comment: You mean a *join table* ? 1-1 does not use a join table. 1-N **can** use a join table if you configure it to. See 1-N in http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/one_to_many_collection.html and 1-1 in http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/one_to_one.html   These are all in the JPA standard. Its for you to pick the appropriate mapping to get what you want to achieve (which you haven't made clear)

Comment: Agree :) I didn't make it clear enough.

Ok - so the 1-1 case holds a settings_id while the organization_settings just has a PK id? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. The FK is on the owner side.